How to change value of textview in activity A after clicking on button which is present in activity B in android?
I have two activities in my app. In Activity A (MainActivity.kt) I have two buttons named buttonGo and buttonCounter. If I click on buttonGo it will go to another activity B (Second.kt). What I want to achieve is, everytime I click on buttonCounter the textCounter(Textview) present in activity B should increment by 1. Currently, no increment takes place.
MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var counterViewModel: CounterViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        counterViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[CounterViewModel::class.java]

        binding.buttonGo.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Second::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        binding.buttonCounter.setOnClickListener {
            counterViewModel.incrementCounter()
        }
    }
}

Second.kt
class Second:AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var  counterViewModel: CounterViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: SecondBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = SecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        counterViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[CounterViewModel::class.java]

        binding.buttonBack.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }

        counterViewModel.counter.observe(this, Observer {count ->
            binding.textCounter.text = count.toString()
        })
    }
}

Below is my viewModel named CounterViewModel.kt
class CounterViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _counter = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val counter: LiveData<Int> get() = _counter

    fun incrementCounter() {
        _counter.value = (_counter.value ?: 0) + 1
    }
}

This is the layout file of MainActivity.kt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_Counter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Counter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_Go" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

This is my layout file for Second.kt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textCounter" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I created a Viewmodel to observe the data changes, created a function for incrementing but the textCounter is not incrementing from its initial value of 0.

Your counter is not updating because each time you change activity new instance of view model is created (you can check it by adding log to overrided onCleared method).
So you have at least 4 options:

Make a model that your view model will be depend on and save state there (but you must ensure that you will use the same instance of model).
Use the same view model in both activities
Save counter value permanently (prefs, file or some other db)
Send current value from one activity to other with "extra" (not recommended :))


@DawidCzopek Can you help me by providing code? i have tried prefs also in my main project but i am having same issue.

My bad. Option 2 is factually not possible as Amardurai mention, this approach could be done with fragments.

You can't share a ViewModel across Activities. However, there are two ways to pass data between activities:
1.Intent : You can pass data between activities using Intent. For example, you can pass the counter value from MainActivity to Second activity via Intent.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var counter = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.buttonGo.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Second::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("counter", counter)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        binding.buttonCounter.setOnClickListener {
            counter++
        }
    }
}

class Second : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: SecondBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = SecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val counter = intent.getIntExtra("counter", 0)
        binding.textCounter.text = counter.toString()

        binding.buttonBack.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}

2.SharedPreferences : You can use SharedPreferences to hold the counter data and retrieve it whenever the activity is recreated. This method persists data even if the app is closed.
CounterViewModel.kt
class CounterViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val preferences = application.getSharedPreferences("counter_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    private val _counter = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    val counter: LiveData<Int> get() = _counter

    init {
        _counter.value = preferences.getInt("counter", 0)
    }

    fun incrementCounter() {
        val newValue = (_counter.value ?: 0) + 1
        _counter.value = newValue
        preferences.edit().putInt("counter", newValue).apply()
    }
}

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var counterViewModel: CounterViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        counterViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[CounterViewModel::class.java]

        binding.buttonGo.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Second::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        binding.buttonCounter.setOnClickListener {
            counterViewModel.incrementCounter()
        }
    }
}

Second.kt
class Second : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var counterViewModel: CounterViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: SecondBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = SecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        counterViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application))[CounterViewModel::class.java]

        counterViewModel.counter.observe(this, Observer { count ->
            binding.textCounter.text = count.toString()
        })

        binding.buttonBack.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}


Thank you so much, I followed your second method
